# circular internal method call

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 internal methods in the .m file declared (not in the @interface) each calling the other.
What do I have to do, that the second method is known in the first method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add to the ***.m*** file:

```
@interface MyClass()
-(void)somePrivateMethod1;
-(void)somePrivateMethod2;
@end

@implementaton MyClass
-(id)init
{
   ...
   [self somePrivateMethod1];
   return self;
}
-(void)somePrivateMethod1
{
   NSLog(@"somePrivateMethod1");
   [self somePrivateMethod2];
}
-(void)somePrivateMethod2
{
   NSLog(@"somePrivateMethod2");
}
@end
```